# Masking external domain with Apache2

Tags: apache-2.2, domain, mod-rewrite

Let say, that you own domain `www.example.com` and have another project on another domain on server that you do not have control: `www.sub.notmine.example.org`.

And you want an user do navigate to `www.mydomain.com` and display content from `www.sub.notminedomain.com` but in the browser you want that user will see `www.example.com`, so there is no sign that `www.sub.notmine.example.org` is used.

Also you want to give the user the opportunity to bookmark the page with `www.example.com`.

How to set up domain `www.example.com` on your server asuming that you are using `Apache2` ?

Comment: That's what mod_proxy is for.

Comment: @JennyD where I can find this information?

Comment: http://httpd.apache.org is the place to start.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use proxy module to achieve such a things. Please refer below Vhost syntax.

```
<VirtualHost IP_ADDRESS:80>
     ServerName www.example.com
     DocumentRoot /var/www/html/
     ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
     CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

     ProxyPreserveHost On
     ProxyPass / http://www.sub.notmine.example.org/
     ProxyPassReverse / http://www.sub.notmine.example.org/     
</VirtualHost>
```

Make sure mod_proxy is loaded in http.conf before starting apache server.